# Расшифровка шестнадцатеричной строки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как расшифровать вот такие слова, в js коде

```
\u0422\u0435\u0440\u0440\u0438\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u044F
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var string = '\u0422\u0435\u0440\u0440\u0438\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u044F';
console.log(unescape(string));
//Территория
```

Comment: Ну, а если в коде этого много?
 Есть утилы, что бы привести это в человеческий вид

Comment: Ну, например, http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/

Comment: @Vlmake vim, например

    :s,\\u\(\x\+\),\=nr2char("0x".submatch(1)),g

Данное слово -- "Территория"

Answer (score 1):

## 2019

> Т.к. unescape является устаревшей, используйте decodeURI или decodeURIComponent вместо неё.

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

```js
console.log(
  decodeURI('\u0422\u0435\u0440\u0440\u0438\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u044F')
)
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что `console.log('\u0422\u0435\u0440\u0440\u0438\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u044F')` тоже превосходно работает?

Comment: @andreymal то есть JS сам всегда приводит такую строку к норм виду если там `\u`? Я просто увидел залайкали `unescape`, но она устарела.